# jQuery - $this instead of $(this)?

Tags: jquery

I think that i read something that said that it is better for code like this:

```
var id1 = $(this).attr('id') 
var id2 = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id') 
var text = $(this).text()
```

..to give one variable like `$this = $(this)` and then use it instead of every $(this). I don't know where i read this, so my question is that is it true?

Comment: The construction of an `$(this)` object is measured in microseconds which means that there is **no** practical performance improvement when using a variable to cache that object. I personally prefer `$(this)` over `$this`.

Comment: Hmm.. But theoretically there is a little difference?

Comment: @Criss Yes, a bunch of microseconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can

```
var $this = $(this);
var id1 = $this.attr('id'); 
var id2 = $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id') ;
var text = $this.text();
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can, but i ask that is it better to do this.

Comment: So this is it waht I looking for. Sorry for editing Yuor answer. I edit it because I forget to remove comments from my example code.

Answer (score 2):

This saves some time on wrapping up the `this` object in the jQuery array-like collection every time you use it. So short answer: yes, but the difference shouldn't be big.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right, yes. Here's an example:

```
var t = $(this);
var id1 = t.attr('id'); 
var id2 = t.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id') ;
var text = t.text();
```

Comment: Sorry for editing your answer, i missed remove comments from code. So You say that assigning $(this) to variable? Ok, so I will be doing my job like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is assigning selectors to local var then you're right. This has something to do with Javascript's  scope nature.

If I remember correctly when you use a local var then variable lookup is faster. Especially if you are using a selector multiple times.

I dunno where you read it but I watched a video about this on Google Developer Stuff.

I dont remember the original video but check this [video](http://vimeo.com/18846584). It is a good watch.

Also check [this](http://www.slideshare.net/AddyOsmani/jquery-proven-performance-tips-tricks) slide

Comment: SO if assingning selectors give better performance, this is it.

Comment: @Sinan You're not assigning selectors to a variable, but a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add few more points to this

the following is called caching and its used to improve performance in DOM manipulation, 
the following code will cache the object and won't query the DOM everytime you do any operation on $this.

```
var $this = $(this);
var id1 = $this.attr('id');
```

the $(this) might be little more expense as everytime it has to do query on DOM

```
var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Just like I think but I need to ensure. Thanks.

Comment: @Cris , yeah mainly it is used when you are doing animations or doing an append or .html etc ,

Comment: one more point you can declare any object , no need to add $ also

Comment: I know that i don't need to add $ but thanks for every suggestions :)

Comment: Actually `$(this)` is pure jQuery code.  There's no querying of the DOM.  It's just wrapping a known DOM object `this` inside a jQuery object.  It is faster to avoid doing it multiple times, but it's not because of DOM queries.