# How can i send data via post request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have form which data will be sent via ajax. It is normal string-type content from textarea. But i don't know how can i tell jquery that i want sent this words as `data`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Could someone can give me any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var data = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: @Cris: as usual? Did I answer some of your question as first? :p

Comment: But something is not as through my thoughts, when i submit form i getting all `<textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content">This is my content</textarea>` as content, but i need only that what is between <textarea> tags. Could it be because something is missing to my jquery code, which is Your written here code?

Comment: You answer this of my questions as firstone, i think:
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719846/jquery-this-instead-of-this`

Comment: I have good memory to faces :) So now, could You say something about why i getting to my database: `<textarea id="id_content" rows="10" cols="40" name="content">This is my content</textarea>`? I think that it is because of jquery code. Could it be that my content is serialized with tags and then send?

Comment: it's probably problem on server-side itself. you could create new question and link it here

Comment: Thanks. I am checking my side-server about code, but still without solution. When i be sure that i do what i can with my skills i will create new question and link it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = $("#my-text-area").val()
```

or maybe I misunderstood your question...

Comment: OP is asking about the **form**, not a single **field**, I suppose. Otherwise you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.serialize()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: $("#YourFormIdHere").serialize(),
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text area has an id:

```
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

then you would send it like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: "data="+$('#myText').val(),
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: my textarea has other id for every added by someone things